# compare 2 csv files and output columns with same gene names

Tags: csv, awk, compare

I have 2 csv files:

```
$ cat file1
ENST00000423372.3|ENSG00000237683.5|-|-|AL627309.1-201|AL627309.1|2661|UTR5:1-70|CDS:71-850|UTR3:851-2661|  52.6643
ENST00000332831.2|ENSG00000185097.2|OTTHUMG00000002581.1|OTTHUMT00000007334.1|OR4F16-001|OR4F16|995|UTR5:1-19|CDS:20-958|UTR3:959-995|  0.034
ENST00000599533.1|ENSG00000269831.1|-|-|AL669831.1-201|AL669831.1|129|CDS:1-129|    8.3949
ENST00000281156.4|ENSG00000112232.8|OTTHUMG00000014936.2|OTTHUMT00000041066.2|KHDRBS2-001|KHDRBS2|2332|UTR5:1-279|CDS:280-1329|UTR3:1330-2332|  3.3232
```

and file2 (tab delimited) which has this gene names in the last column.

```
$ cat -A file2
chr5^I57444505^I57444664^I+^IIntergenic^IIntergenic^I-26416^INR_104669^I^ILINC02101$
chr6^I62712636^I62712786^I+^Iintron (NR_146874, intron 3 of 13)^IAT_rich|Low_complexity|Low_complexity^I283419^INR_146874^IENSG00000112232^IKHDRBS2$
chr13^I98046123^I98046340^I+^I3' UTR (NM_001306070, exon 8 of 8)^I3' UTR (NM_001306070, exon 8 of 8)^I-40192^INM_021033^IENSG00000125249^IRAP2A$
chr6^I138854092^I138854316^I+^Iintron (NM_020464, intron 1 of 6)^Iintron (NM_020464, intron 1 of 6)^I-33573^INM_001144060^IENSG00000135540^INHSL1$
chr14^I98430462^I98430676^I+^Iintron (NR_152748, intron 2 of 2)^Iintron (NR_152748, intron 2 of 2)^I13892^INR_152746^IENSG00000246223^ILINC01550$
chr11^I10444849^I10445062^I+^Iintron (NR_103765, intron 3 of 3)^IL1PA7|LINE|L1^I-26913^INM_001172431^IENSG00000133805^IAMPD3$
chr12^I50549011^I50549204^I+^Iintron (NM_001331069, intron 1 of 11)^Iintron (NM_001331069, intron 1 of 11)^I12045^INM_001331073^IENSG00000139624^ICERS5$
chrX^I154682687^I154682793^I+^IIntergenic^ITHE1B|LTR|ERVL-MaLR^I-4438^INR_036260^IENSG00000221603^IMIR1184-3$
```

I want a script to check gene name from the first file and look for the same in the second file, and if it matches , generate a file containing both the values.
The output should be like

> KHDRBS2 3.3232

I wrote an awk script :

```
awk -F"|" 'FILENAME=="file1"{A[$1]=$1} FILENAME=="file2"{if(A[$10]==$10){print}}'
```

but it does not produce any ouput. Can someone please help and tell me where I am wrong here ?

Regards.

Comment: it simply runs and produces no output

Comment: Do you really have csv files ( comma separated values )?  I see that you have -F,  , but the input file looks to be pipe "|" delimited.    In fact, your sample input has no commas.  Perhaps you just need to change your -F"," to -F"|" .

Comment: assuming file2's delimiter is `|`, I only see 3 fields (in the sample data) but the `awk` script is referencing a 10th field (`$10`); or does file2 have a different delimiter?

Comment: I am sorry , yes the file 2 has a different delimiter, it is tab separated. I am new to informatics, I apologize for the mistake.

Comment: What is your expected output and what are column numbers of gene in both files?

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```sh
awk -F '|' 'FNR == NR {map[$6] = $NF; next}
$NF in map {print $10, map[$10]}' file1 FS='\t' file2

KHDRBS2   3.3232
```

Comment: re: changing FS for the 2nd file ... I haven't seen that before! +1

Answer (score 2):

You can convert to the same delimiter and then keep the data from the first file and print from the second file.

Given:

```
cat file_1
ENST00000423372.3|ENSG00000237683.5|-|-|AL627309.1-201|AL627309.1|2661|UTR5:1-70|CDS:71-850|UTR3:851-2661|  52.6643
ENST00000332831.2|ENSG00000185097.2|OTTHUMG00000002581.1|OTTHUMT00000007334.1|OR4F16-001|OR4F16|995|UTR5:1-19|CDS:20-958|UTR3:959-995|  0.034
ENST00000599533.1|ENSG00000269831.1|-|-|AL669831.1-201|AL669831.1|129|CDS:1-129|    8.3949
ENST00000281156.4|ENSG00000112232.8|OTTHUMG00000014936.2|OTTHUMT00000041066.2|KHDRBS2-001|KHDRBS2|2332|UTR5:1-279|CDS:280-1329|UTR3:1330-2332|  3.3232

cat file_2
chr5^I57444505^I57444664^I+^IIntergenic^IIntergenic^I-26416^INR_104669^I^ILINC02101$
chr6^I62712636^I62712786^I+^Iintron (NR_146874, intron 3 of 13)^IAT_rich|Low_complexity|Low_complexity^I283419^INR_146874^IENSG00000112232^IKHDRBS2$
chr13^I98046123^I98046340^I+^I3" UTR (NM_001306070, exon 8 of 8)^I3" UTR (NM_001306070, exon 8 of 8)^I-40192^INM_021033^IENSG00000125249^IRAP2A$
chr6^I138854092^I138854316^I+^Iintron (NM_020464, intron 1 of 6)^Iintron (NM_020464, intron 1 of 6)^I-33573^INM_001144060^IENSG00000135540^INHSL1$
chr14^I98430462^I98430676^I+^Iintron (NR_152748, intron 2 of 2)^Iintron (NR_152748, intron 2 of 2)^I13892^INR_152746^IENSG00000246223^ILINC01550$
chr11^I10444849^I10445062^I+^Iintron (NR_103765, intron 3 of 3)^IL1PA7|LINE|L1^I-26913^INM_001172431^IENSG00000133805^IAMPD3$
chr12^I50549011^I50549204^I+^Iintron (NM_001331069, intron 1 of 11)^Iintron (NM_001331069, intron 1 of 11)^I12045^INM_001331073^IENSG00000139624^ICERS5$
chrX^I154682687^I154682793^I+^IIntergenic^ITHE1B|LTR|ERVL-MaLR^I-4438^INR_036260^IENSG00000221603^IMIR1184-3$
```

You can do:

```
awk -F "|" 'FNR==NR{arr[$6]=$11; next}
$1 in arr{print $1, arr[$1]}
' file_1 <(awk -F "^" '{print substr($NF, 2, length($NF) - 2)}' file_2)
KHDRBS2   3.3232
```

If file 2 is `\t` separated vs `^`, use that delimiter instead. I have the line `substr($NF, 2, length($NF) - 2)` processing the second file since you seem to have an extra `I` and `$` in that file. Adjust accordingly.

---

I realize there are `|` in file 2. In this case, that does not really matter since we are just using the last field.

If you *were* referencing a numbered field in file_2 and this change would be an issue, you can standardize on some other delimiter (like `\t`):

```
awk -F "\t" 'FNR==NR{arr[$6]=$11; next}
$NF in arr{print $NF, arr[$NF]}
' <(awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS="\t"}$1=$1' file_1) \
<(awk  'BEGIN{FS="\\^I"; OFS="\t"} {sub(/\$$/,"")}$1=$1' file_2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Reconstituting `file2` from OP's `cat -A file2`:

```
$ vi file2.raw                                   # cut-n-pasted OP's 'cat -A file2' into my 'file2.raw'
$ sed 's/\^I/\t/g;s/\$//' file2.raw > file2
```

Since the 2 input files have different delimiters (`file1` delimiter = `|`; `file2` delimiter = `\t`) we'll skip using the `awk -F` flag and instead use a couple `split()` calls to break the lines into components.

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '

# process 1st file

FNR==NR { split($0,x,"|")
          gene=x[6]
          value=x[11]
          genes[gene]=value
          next
        }

# process 2nd file

        { split($0,x,"\t")
          gene=x[10]
          if ( gene in genes )
             print gene,genes[gene]
        }
' file1 file2
```

**NOTE:** the code can be reduced by eliminating the `gene` and `value` variables and just referencing the `x[]` entries directly

This generates:

```
KHDRBS2   3.3232
```